# How long can a Timelord hold his breath?

Tags: doctor-who

In the episode *Deep Breath*, the way living species can disguise themselves as clockworks is to hold their breath. It looks like the Doctor has been able to do that for a very long time (at least 10 minutes, based on the time he spent disguised in the larder).

Are there other occasions where we learn how long a Time Lord can hold their breath?

Comment: From an out of universe perspective there are techniques which can be implemented to hold one's breath for 'super-human' lengths. Nothing as high as 10 minutes, as far as I know, but if it does turn out there's no canon that the Doctor can hold his breath, there's always these methods which can be supplied as a potential explination. ETA: strike what I said about length -- humans can apparently hold their breath upwards of 22 minutes, in the case of a world record diver.

Comment: @MacCooper: It should however be added that in addition to being a world-class trained diver, those 22 minutes are outright cheating (breathing pressurized 100% oxygen for a few mins before starting), which not just saturates haemoglobin to 100% but also brings a considerable amount of oxygen into solution in plasma and cell water (not normally the case) and obviously leaves several times the normal amount of oxygen in the lungs. Then again, who said a timelord _couldn't_ be cheating (by locally halting time, if nothing else) in addition to being an alien.

Comment: For as long as necessary to enable him to find some [celery](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Celery).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Doctor, like all Galifreyans can hold his breath for a very long time (upwards of ten to fifteen minutes) using his famous "[Respiratory Bypass System](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Respiratory_bypass_system)", an evolutionary trait which he has used on numerous occasions to avoid gas, to prevent himself from suffocating and to ignore strong smells:

From **TV: [The Robots of Death](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/14-5.htm)**

> **LEELA:** *Doctor, why didn't the helium make your voice go squeaky?*
>
> **DOCTOR:** *Because I'm a Time Lord. I've been around, you know. Two
>   hearts, **respiratory bypass system.** I haven't lived seven hundred
>   and fifty years without learning something. After you. Little mouse.*

From **TV : [The Caves of Androzani](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/21-6.htm)**

> **DOCTOR:** ***I can store oxygen for several minutes,*** Jek. Now, you must do everything you can to keep her temperature down until I get
>   back.
>
> **JEK:** *Doctor, wait! I have just one oxygen cylinder left. I used it when I went into the baking chambers of the refinery. It will run
>   out in minutes, but it might help.*

From the **Prose Story :** **[A Town Called Eternity](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/A_Town_Called_Eternity_(short_story))**

> They dragged him the short distance to the gallows outside the
>   jailhouse and then they hoisted him up. **They watched him swing for a
>   full quarter of an hour,** with him too weak even to struggle or choke,
>   before they cut him down.
>
> The undertaker had fled the moment the Doctor spoke to him.
>   Unsurprising, really, thought the Doctor, rubbing his bruised throat.
>   Unfortunately, most victims of a lynch mob didn't have a respiratory
>   bypass system to fall back on. On Gallifrey, hangings were less a form
>   of justice, more a risky hobby for seedy Cardinals with regenerations
>   to spare.

Comment: Great and very well documented answer! Thank you!

Comment: Ew that last sentence

Comment: There was also The Pyramids of Mars where the Doctor was supposedly strangled but after a short while began to breathe.

And in the Terror of the Zygons he was trapped in a pressurised tank where he hypnotised Sarah into not breathing before stopping his own breathing.

Comment: @nigelellis - I considered adding both but concluded that neither demonstrate the length of time that he can hold his breath while remaining active

Comment: @Richard A good point; PoM could be a defence mechanism, but TotZ was at least a conscious decision not to breathe. Unfortunately there was no on screen indications of time.

Comment: @nigelellis - precisely, whereas the others all show that its been at least a few minutes rather than (possibly) just a few seconds.

Comment: @NigelEllis PoM is however the first occasion on which the respiratory bypass is named (according to the Discontinuity Guide) and could therefore probably be added to your answer on that basis.

Comment: Without looking it up, I recall there was also an episode where the fourth doctor episode has to go outside a space ship, and is telling Adric how long he could hold his breath in the vacuum of space.

Comment: @michael - If memory serves, in that case he went into a trance, which is why I excluded it.